# Is There any way to get the beacon battery life when using iBeacon protocol?

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, ibeacon

Is there any way to retrieve a battery voltage from my iBeacon?
Maybe adding a byte somewhere in the advertising packet to present the value of the battery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no standard way to do this with iBeacon.  Other formats like AltBeacon and Eddystone-TLM do include a data byte to transmit the battery level.

Many hardware beacons support interleaving multiple beacon transmissions from the same hardware device,  so even if you need iBeacon, you could still transmit the battery level in one of these other formats.

Comment: But, isn't that affect the battery of the beacon? - talking about transmitting two protocols, also what about interference? if I am using the Bluetooth signals (from iBeacon) to detect my location then the Eddystone-TLM may affect the iBeacon signal?

Comment: This is a common approach and interference is not an issue as a single device sends two packets one after another.  This approach will use proportionally more battery power, although some hardware beacons let you configure individual advertising rates for each beacon frame, so you could have iBeacon at 10 Hz and AltBeacon at 1 Hz, and only use 10% more power for AltBeacon.